# Reload Partial in Form After Submitting 2nd Form - c#

Tags: javascript, html, forms, radio-button, html-helper

I am working on creating a form that includes a selection (radio, but open to drop down or other) that is populated from a sql query, based off a user-entered search.

For example, if my selection is Location, I need to allow users to search for "California" and then see a list cities in California. The list of options is over 20k so I do not want users to see the whole list - they need to be able to search / filter down to a reasonable amount of options. (The filtering of the list will be on the database side, and a stored procedure is handling the logic.)

Ideally the form would look like this:

```
Field 1: [text]
---------------- (inserted partial)
Search: [text area] [submit button] --> sends of an sql query and reloads partial
Field 2: radio buttons --> these options loaded from sql query
---------------- (end partial)
Field 3: [text]
[submit button] --> submits all 3 field values to form handler
```

Here is my Primary Form HTML:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<div class="form-group">
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Field1, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
  <div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Field1, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Field1, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  @Html.Action("Field2_Lookup", "Field2", new { });
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Field3, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
  <div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Field3, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Field3, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
}
```

And here's the HTML for the partial for Field2:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Field2_Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.TextBox("SearchString")
                    <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-10">
                @if (Model != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in Model.Field2)
                {
                        <input type="radio" name="@Model.Field2_Name" value="@item.Field2" id="item.Field2_ID">@item.Field2<br />
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => item.Field2, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    }
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Field2 Controller:

```
public ActionResult Field2_Lookup(string searchTerm)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTerm))
        {
            return View(DB.Field2_LookUp(searchTerm));
        }
        //Only return values if there is a searchTerm. If not, return an empty partial.
        return View();
    }
```

In terms of user flow, when the form page loads, the Field2 partial should be empty and the user needs to enter text into the search field, press "search" button, and then the partial reloads with the options from the sql query.

So my questions are:

1. How do I have the Field2 Search button only end the form of the search? (Currently this button ends the entire page's form.)
2. How do I reload just the partial, passing the controller the searchTerm?
3. How do I pass the Field2 selection value to the general form?

I know I need to use JavaScript, but I'm not sure on implementation (and I'm new to JavaScript). Any pointers in the right direction are greatly appreciated!!!

I am working with MVC Entity Framework, Visual Studio 2015, C#, JavaScript, bootstrap, etc.

Answer (score 0):

1. I'm not sure what you mean by this, can you rephrase this question?
2. All you have to do here is return a partial view instead. It ought to look something like this:

   `return PartialView("PartialViewName", value(s) you want to pass back to view);`
3. Having a little trouble understanding this question as well. It sounds to me like you should create a model, and use that instead to pass your data.